# how to check image aspect ratio before drop image into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to check image aspect ratio if image aspect ratio greater then drop div then drop image if image aspect ratio less then div then not drop image

```
 function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));       
    }
```

Comment: In your `drop` function divide the width of the element by it's height and compare.

Comment: i need drop div multiple and each divs height width different so image check div height width if less then image aspect ratio then image drop into div if image aspect ratio less then div then image is not drop into div

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you just want to check the aspect ratios in your drop function and then either allow the image to be inserted or not.

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var divRatio = $('#div').width() / $('#div').height();
    var imageRatio = $('#div').width() / $('#div').height();
    if (imageRatio <= divRatio) {
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }    
}
```